# Is it possible to serialize caliburn.micro bindablecollection ver 3.0.3?

Tags: c#, serialization, caliburn.micro

there.

I want to serialize '**BindableCollection**' class in 'Caliburn.Micro ver=3.0.3'.

I could serialize it in version 1.5.2.
Maybe because there was **'using System.Runtime.Serialization;**'.

But in 3.0.3, there is no **'using System.Runtime.Serialization'**.
So it shows me error when I compiled it.

Could you help me to serialize '**BindableCollection**' class in 'Caliburn.Micro ver=3.0.3'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From 1.5.2 to 3.03 there was a change to the code based resulting in `[DataContract]` was only in the PropertyChangeBase.cs, so you would have to annotate your member properties with `[DataMember]`, if you are using PropertyChangeBase as part of your model.

That being side if you don't then you would have to reference that namespace yourself and annotate your class and your member properties to properly serialize.